# set current language in malay for yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I'm new here.
I have problem to set current language in yii to malay language. This is my current code in config/main.php:

```
'sourceLanguage'=>'ms',
```

But it does not affect at all.but if i change the code to:

```
'sourceLanguage'=>'id',
```

The current language change to Indonesia language.

Could someone please tell me the code for malay language?

Answer (score 0):

Please check with **ms-my** for Malay - Malaysia and **ms-bn** for Malay - Brunei.

Comment: i put it like this: 'sourceLanguage'=>'ms-my', but it display in english language which is default.